# Persistir objetos filhos com o id do pai 1:N

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, java-8

Galera estou com dificuldade em relacionamentos com hibernate, eu tenho um relacionamento 1:N entre Prestador e Endereço (1 prestador pode ter N endereços). Meu problema é o seguinte, quando eu tento persistir um prestador ele também tenta persistir o endereço (o que é certo), o problema é que ele ta tentando persistir o endereço sem colocar o id do Prestador na coluna de foreing key que eu defini com not null.

```
//Classe de Prestador
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prestador", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnderecoEntity> enderecos;
```

```
//Classe de Endereço
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_prestador")
private PrestadorEntity prestador;
```

```
//Ao chamar o repositorio para salvar o prestador ele executa os seguintes comandos
Hibernate: insert into prestador (nome, path_foto) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into endereco (cep, cidade, estado, logradouro, numero) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

```
//Erro que está acontecendo informando que a fk não tem um valor padrão (porque está null)
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'fk_prestador' doesn't have a default value
```

```
{
    "nome": "Teste",
    "enderecos": [
        {
            "cep": 999999,
            "logradouro": "Rua Teste",
            "numero": 4,
            "cidade": "Maceió",
            "estado": "Alagoas"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: posta sua entidade completa, não precisa dos get e set mas os atributos são indispensáveis. qual foi a estratégia de geração de ID?

Comment: Em ambas as classes a geração de id é feita pela anotação @Id e @GeneratedValue(IDENTITY)... o atributo é um Long

Comment: Seu sistema usa algum script DDL pra criar a base de dados? Se sim, você definiu nele que o id do prestador vai ser autogerado?

Comment: @StatelessDev eu não uso nenhum sript para criar a base... eu mesmo a criei, coloquei os id's como auto_increment e na tabela endereco adicionei a fk de prestador com FOREIGN KEY (fk_prestador) REFERENCES prestador(id)